# Django cannot delete on shell

Tags: python, django

I was trying to a delete user. But it doesn't work. I tried it on a shell.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> a = User.objects.get(username='zayn')
>>> a.delete()
```

I got the following error.

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "girl_user_profile" does not exist
```

Comment: Looks like you added a profile model but haven't migrated yet. Run `makemigrations` & `migrate` then try again.

Comment: It's working. You right, I forgot to makemigrations it. Thank you si much!!